# Why $x=x$? Why $x=y$ and $y=z$ imply $x=z$? (Assume, $x$, $y$ and $z$ are reals.)

Tags: calculus, logic, real-numbers, axioms

I recently have been studying the axiomatic construction of the set of real numbers through the Peano axioms for the natural numbers. It seems to me, the only things needed to proceed with this body of knowledge, is some basic set theory (ZFC axioms) plus the rules of mathematical logic. However, I noticed that from time to time one needs the facts mentioned in the title. Now, these are self-explanatory and self-evident of course but since I am so deep in the roots of modern mathematics, I thought I should inquire about those as well. After all, Euclid states a similar axiom in his Elements: «if each one of two line segments is equal to a third one, then they are equal.»

So, regarding real numbers, where did these rules come from?

- Are they axioms of some sort and if yes from which theory?
- Are they simply some statement formulas of boolean logic? If so, how
  is one to be convinced of their validity?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Axioms 2-4 [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Formulation) explicitly assume this.

Comment: The basic properties of $=$ (and other basic facts) are assumed at the level of [first-order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic) itself. We can of course consider alternate logical systems, but that's where those basic facts are "built in."

Comment: Since you're building up the real number system from the natural numbers, you must be using some set theory to provide the needed tools for that construction (Dedekind cuts, equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences, etc.). In most modern set theories, equality and its basic properties are taken as given in the underlying logic. In some older set theories, equality was defined: for example, some authors defined $x=y$ to mean $\forall z\,(z\in x\iff z\in y)$. Then the definition makes it easy to prove basic properties of equality like those you asked about.

Comment: Just to clarify, is your second question how we can *rigorously* see that these are theorems, or how one justifies them informally?

Comment: @Malice Vidrine rigorously, thanks

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. Let me read some of this first order logic. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

> Are they axioms of some sort and if yes from which theory?

Yhe they are the first-order logic [axioms for equlity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms).